# How to fix Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js)?

Tags: javascript, babeljs, babel-loader

While trying to start the project I have the following error:

**Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'C:\Users\user\Documents\signatura-web\node_modules@babel\preset-es2015' imported from C:\Users\user\Documents\signatura-web\babel-virtual-resolve-base.js**.

I have @babel packages installed (7th version) and babel-loader (8th version).

Here is **package.json** file:

```
{
  "name": "signatura-web",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "private": true,
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --open --mode development --env dev",
    "build": "webpack --mode production --env stage",
    "build:prod": "webpack --mode production --env prod",
    "serve": "node prodServer.js",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://Evgeny.Smirennikov@bitbucket.axamit.com/scm/sgt/signatura-web.git"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.10.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.10.4",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.11.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.3",
    "@babel/preset-es2015": "^7.0.0-beta.53",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.10.1",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.12.7",
    "@svgr/webpack": "^5.4.0",
    "@types/react-datepicker": "^4.3.3",
    "@types/react-notifications-component": "^2.4.0",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.11",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.2",
    "@types/yup": "^0.29.13",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.12.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.12.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^6.4.0",
    "css-loader": "^3.6.0",
    "eslint": "^8.21.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.6.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.30.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin": "^6.0.4",
    "html-loader": "^1.1.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.3.0",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.9.0",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1",
    "react-datetime": "2.16.3",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",
    "style-loader": "^1.2.1",
    "stylus-loader": "^3.0.2",
    "ts-loader": "^8.0.11",
    "typescript": "^4.1.2",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@beyonk/google-fonts-webpack-plugin": "^1.5.0",
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^1.0.0",
    "@logtail/browser": "^0.1.12",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "@types/react-input-mask": "^3.0.1",
    "animejs": "^3.2.1",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.2",
    "braintree-web-drop-in-react": "^1.2.1",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "compute-scroll-into-view": "^1.0.17",
    "connected-react-router": "^6.8.0",
    "copy-to-clipboard": "^3.3.1",
    "date-fns": "^2.29.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "file-loader": "^6.1.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "google-map-react": "^2.1.9",
    "headroom.js": "^0.11.0",
    "html-react-parser": "^1.4.8",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "moment": "^2.26.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "openvidu-browser": "2.16.0",
    "pdfjs-dist": "^3.0.279",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-addons-css-transition-group": "^15.6.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.3.0",
    "react-bootstrap-typeahead": "^5.1.1",
    "react-datepicker": "^4.5.0",
    "react-document-meta": "^3.0.0-beta.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dropzone": "^11.1.0",
    "react-ga": "^3.3.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^6.9.6",
    "react-input-mask": "^2.0.4",
    "react-modal": "^3.11.2",
    "react-notifications-component": "^2.4.1",
    "react-paginate": "^6.5.0",
    "react-progressive-graceful-image": "^0.6.14",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-select": "^3.1.0",
    "react-spinners": "^0.9.0",
    "react-string-replace": "^0.4.4",
    "react-tabs": "^3.1.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "^17.0.1",
    "reactstrap": "^8.5.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-persist-transform-filter": "^0.0.20",
    "redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.7",
    "sass-loader": "^10.0.2",
    "stylus": "^0.54.8",
    "yup": "^0.29.3"
  },
  "homepage": "./",
  "jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(css|styl|svg)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    }
  }
}
```

Here is **.babelrc** file:

```
{
  "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      "@babel/preset-react",
      "@babel/preset-typescript",
      "@babel/preset-es2015"
  ],
  "plugins": [
      [
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
      ]
  ]
}
```

Among **rules** in webpack.config.js I have:

```
 {
   test: /\.(js|jsx|tsx)$/,
   exclude: /node_modules/,
   use: {
     loader: "babel-loader",
    },
 },
```

Comment: did you try to delete node_modules & package-lock.json then retry?

Comment: Yes I tried to do that